# Mutating across multiple columns to create percent score in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm attempting to reproduce the following code across 36 seperate columns in a df. So instead of having to retype this code 36 times, how can I apply a function to apply this for all columns at once? The columns in the df I need to apply them to are 4:40.

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(percent_score_1 = (score_1 / 5) * 100,
         percent_score_2 = (score_2 / 5) * 100)
```

The data looks like this:

```
   score_1   score_2
     2           3
     3           4
     5           1
```

In case it is not clear, I am creating a percent score variable based on questions out of 5 points.

Thanks!!

Comment: since the columns are from 4:44, you could do `across(4:44, ....)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do:

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(starts_with('score'), ~ ./5 * 100, .names = 'percent_{col}'))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the answer I was looking for, especially with specifying the specific columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code below

```
idx <- startsWith(names(df), "score_")
cbind(df, setNames(df[idx] * 5 / 100, paste0("percent_", names(df)[idx])))
```

Answer (score 2):

Write your own function to calculate percentage and use `mutate` with `across`.

```
calculate_percentage <- function(Vector){
  (Vector/5) * 100
}

df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("score"),
                     calculate_percentage))
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: to get the right names we could assign arguments like Onyambu did (credits to him):

```
library(dplyr)

my_percent_score <- function(x) {
    x=(x/5)*100
}

df %>% 
    mutate(across(starts_with('score'), my_percent_score, .names = 'percent_{col}'))
```